# regex to extract a string from begin/end pattern

Tags: regex

I would like to extract the string "1_0" from the input string "some_file_name_V_1_0.xml"

What regex should i use to do that ?

```
I was think of extracting the string 1_0 that is between :
- The begin pattern "_V_"
- The end pattern ".xml"
```

toto_V_2_0.xml in input should return 2_0

Thanks for your help,

Regards,

Comment: The *"I was thinking"* part sounds good. How did you perform on the *"I was trying"* part? Post your attempt and where you got stuck. Also tag the question with the language or tool you need the `regex` for.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following pattern:

```
^.*?V_(.*)\.xml$
```

and then check the first capture group for the version string.